Movie about a single dad raising a daughter
I am looking for a live action movie set in the early 2000's. I believe it is set in New York.
A single dad raising a daughter meets a reporter who has sex with him after realizing he hasn't had sex since his wife died. His daughter walks in on them while they have sex in the shower. The daughter chides her father saying he is the one who told her only married couples are supposed to show each other their private parts. This is in reference to the girl and a boy showing each other their privates. 
I believe the dad is a garbage collector.

Could it be Jersey Girl?
A 2004 movie by Kevin Smith starring Ben Affleck and Liv Tyler.
Plot from wikipedia :

Ollie Trinké (Ben Affleck) is a powerful media publicist in New York City whose wife, Gertie (Jennifer Lopez), dies during childbirth with an aneurysm. To avoid his grief, he buries himself in his work and ignores his new daughter, Gertie, while his father, Bart (George Carlin), takes a month off from work to care for her, but returns so that Ollie is forced to live up to his responsibility as a parent. Under the stress of a botched diaper change and a baby who will not stop crying, he trashes his client, Will Smith, for his soon-to-be released film, Independence Day, in front of assembled reporters. That costs him his job, so he moves in with Bart in New Jersey. He eventually apologizes for ignoring Gertie, and attributes his public outburst to his grief.
Blacklisted by all of New York City's public relations firms, Ollie has to work as a civil servant in the borough where he now lives with Bart. Seven years later, Gertie (Raquel Castro), now in elementary school, often coaxes him to rent films to watch. At the video store, they meet Maya (Liv Tyler), a graduate student and one of the clerks, whose uninhibited probing into Ollie's love life almost leads to them having casual sex. She soon becomes a part of their lives.

Trailer :



I think the scenes you mentionned are present in the trailer at 0:50 (boy and girl showing their privates and then Ollie's reaction) and at 1:16 (Ollie and Maya having sex, and the girl reaction).
